# Android bluetooth pairing randomly unpair

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, pairing

I thought pairing bluetooth was a "long term" process (once your pair it, it is forever), turns out during my tests my devices sometimes stop being paired.

I need a paired device to stay paired : Is the unpairing a normal scenario that I can't prevent ? If not, what could cause this issue and how to solve it ?

Comment: During your test what exactly happens? It doesn't load paired devices?

Comment: I cannot describe you a specific scenario. So basically I pair the devices through my app. it works perfectly until it randomly stop being paired. I tried identifying exaclty what I did when this happen but I'm at loss honestly. So I was wondering if there is an obvious case of unpairing that I don't know about.

Comment: Actually I think it shouldn't unpair randomly.

Comment: That's an interesting answer (no irony inside). That means something is going wrong.

Comment: Its' not answer just my opinion. The underlaying problem might be related with your phone or recent OS update. And I agree on this "I thought pairing bluetooth was a "long term" process". This is bug related with specific devices or specific OS version